# Any way to reset a variable in ruby to its original value

Tags: ruby

Let's say I declared variable `@counter=0` in my `initialize` method, and in some part of my code, I want to reset it again to its original value. Though I can manually do `@counter=0`, I want to know if there is any way to reset it to its original assigned value. something like example: `@counter.reset`

```
def initialize
  @counter = 0
  ...
end
def first
  @some_string.each do |f|
    if f == ''
      @counter += 1 
    end
    @counter = 0 # Want to change it here
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't `@counter = 0` simpler? Or do you mean it may be initialized a value other than `0`?

Comment: yes its simpler but ..just wanted to know whether we have any method to set to its initialized state without manually modifiying it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ..i am sorry dint understand you..

Comment: If you are assigning `@counter = val` in `initialize`, maybe `@counter = @original_counter = val`, `def reset_counter @counter = @original_counter; end`? You can't define a method on an instance variable (i.e., `@counter.reset`).

Comment: If you don't have anything else in `initialize` that would interfere, then call `initialize`.

Comment: sawa, perhaps elaborate "call" as `initialize` is private...

Comment: C.new.send :initialize

Comment: @CarySwoveland Why would you do that? Just write `initialize` within the method body of `First`.

Comment: `c = C.new; c.initialize => NoMethodError: private method `initialize' called for #<C:0x0000010122dd30>`. Did I misunderstand you? Oh, I see. Nevermind.

Comment: so as per my understanding ..there is no quick way to do it like i expected ? ..i would not like to define another method for this and make it more complex instead of just using @counter = 0

Comment: Rahul, we normally use all lower-case letters (and optional underscores) for names of variables and methods (i.e., `first` rather than `First`). Also, `def first` is missing an `end`. Normally when `initialize` is given in a question it is shown to be within a class (e.g., `class MyClass; def initialize...end ... end`), though there is no law that you have to do that. Also, you should test you code in IRB or PRY before posting. That would have turned up the missing `end`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables aren't objects in Ruby, you can't tell them to do anything. There are exactly two things you can do with a variable: assign it and dereference it.

Comment: Good point. I somehow wondered that there would be some way. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, try it:

```
def initialize
    reset_counter
    ...
end

def reset_counter
    @counter = 0;
end

def First
    @some_string.each do |f|
        if f == ''
            @counter += 1 
        end
    end
    reset_counter
end
```

Comment: This works good ..but i still prefer doing @counter = 0 rather than doing this much...i was wondering if there is any snap way to do it.

Comment: if you don't do anything more, the shortest way is as you say: `@counter = 0`